# Consistent Height on Angular material tabs

Tags: angular, angular-material

Scenario:

I have a angular material tabs with two tab inside. Each tab has different height. I need to set the overall height of the tab with the highest height out of the two tabs.

Issue:

The height is not consistent.

[image][image]

How to make the height of the second tab same as first one which is always dynamic?

Sample Code that I have used it in my project:

```
<mat-tab-group dynamicHeight>
  <mat-tab label="Short tab">
    <div class="example-small-box mat-elevation-z4">
      Small content
    </div>
  </mat-tab>
  <mat-tab label="Long tab">
    <div class="example-large-box mat-elevation-z4">
      Large content
    </div>
  </mat-tab>
</mat-tab-group>
```